# How do I repartition a bootable USB?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, partitioning

So today I gave my sister a bootable San Disk USB with Ubuntu on it. However the storage space on it, after being used, went down. When I first created the USB drive, I accidentally only partitioned the drive for about half of it to be Ubuntu (just me badly misunderstanding). I looked it up, and found the diskpart command for command prompt, however the instructions on it wouldn't work with my bootable USB, and I couldn't find any other tutorials that gave results. How could I remove this unused partition just taking up space and add the space from that to Ubuntu?

EDIT: forgot to mention, but I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: do you have a windows PC?

Comment: yeah, I'm on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Download and open Minitool Partition Wizard : https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Then, Select your drive > right click the partition you want to increase in size  and click Extend, follow the on screen instructions , its very easy.

And yes dont forget to click on apply in the top left corner.

Comment: I attempted the instructions, but no Extend option appeared. I don't know if I'm using the wrong partition or what, but I shrunk down the partition with 0% space usage, and attempted to increase the one with 94% usage on it, however it didn't work.

Comment: what file system is your usb drive ?

Comment: the 0% used file system is FAT32, and the 94% used one is EXT4

Comment: can you delete the ununsed partition in Minitool ?

Comment: yes, however it just leaves a bunch of unused space

Comment: post a screenshot of minitool window with right click on the 94% used drive

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/AVreVz3) move/resize doesn't work

Comment: is move/resize also disabled ??

Comment: while it does go into the tool, it can't resize, only move

Comment: you could try to set "partition as primary" but at your own risk...i am not sure about that

Comment: it unfortunately didn't work